# How do I migrate an off-topic question from physics to another stack exchange site?

Tags: support, migration

I had asked a question that had been voted as off-topic and closed.  How do I migrate the question to a more appropriate stack exchange site?

Answer (score 4):

Raise a moderator flag on the question explaining where you want to migrate it. Alternatively you can just ask your question on the target site yourself as a new question, there is no benefit to migrating questions unless they have already received answers that would also be appropriate for the target site.

Comment: I did raise the moderator flag and requested the question be migrated to chemistry and biology.  I haven't heard back yet.  How will I know it's done?

Comment: @0tyranny0poverty You can view all your flags and their status [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/154026). In this case, the flag was declined because 1. you asked to migrate to *two* other SE sites, which is both technically impossible and [undesirable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/263383), 2. there was no apparent benefit to a moderator migrating the question instead of you just asking it yourself at the site you want as I suggested and 3.  it is not completely clear it is on-topic on either of the sites you suggested, either.

Comment: olease, which site would be most appropriate for said question?